# Arc Length of Path with Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Find arc length of path $c(t) = (cos(t), sin(t), t^2)$ from $ 0≤t≤ π$

Rule: $\int \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}
 dx = \frac{1}{2}(x \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}+ a^2 ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 + a^2})
+ C$

My Steps:

$\int_0^{π}\sqrt{sin^2t+cos^2t+(2t)^2}$

$\int_0^{π}\sqrt{1+(2t)^2}$

$x = 2t , a = 1$

By using the rule: $(\frac{1}{2}(2t \sqrt{(2t)^2 + 1^2}+ 1^2 ln(2t + \sqrt{(2t)^2 + 1^2})))|_0^π $

Which is incorrect, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The problem is that you forgot the $dt$. Making $t=\frac u 2$, $dt=\frac 12 du$
$$I=\int\sqrt{1+(2t)^2}\,dt=\frac 12 \int\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du$$

Comment: why do we use "u" if we have the rule $\int \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}
 dx = \frac{1}{2}(x \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}+ a^2 ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 + a^2})
+ C$

Comment: oh wait, so the rule means x^2 as in literally just x

Comment: @mathguy. You got it !